# Sidebar will not float right

Tags: html, css, css-float, sidebar, sticky-footer

I've searched. I've tried. Nothing works yet. I am a newbie, but I have floated divs before with no problem. Is it something to do with the flexbox sticky footer? I have not done that before. I don't see the connection, but who knows. All I need is a main section and sidebar. I can't be that hard. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<section>A technology services company supporting the solid rocket motor industry, airbag igniters, as well as Statistical Process Control support and training for manufacturing industries in general.</section>

<aside class="sidebar">Content for  class "sidebar" Goes Here</aside>

<footer>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">Content for  class "footer" Goes Here</div>
</footer>

</div></body>
</html>


section {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#999999;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.sidebar{
    display: block;
    background-color: #F9E903;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;

}
footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px   
}
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Comment: Here is my entire code. Hope I did this right. I still can't get the sidebar to float right.   https://jsfiddle.net/newsong80/d5yevka0/#&togetherjs=jyu9v6y9Px

Comment: I went back and isolated my "section, sidebar and footer" on a new page by itself. The sidebar finally floated right (but not up beside the main section). When I added back in my wrapper div, the sidebar would not float right at all. I then took out the flex lines of code out of the wrapper div and sidebar went to the right (again, not up beside the main section). So it has to be the flex option. Any thoughts? I really like the responsive sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

It works until mobile for me, at which point the issue is that your 20px of padding on the section element are messing with your percentages. You can do this to fix it, I also added 10% to the section so there's not 10% of extra space in between, but you can reduce it back to 65% if that's intended:

```
section{
  width: calc(75% - 40px);
  padding: 40px;
}
```

Whenever you're using a percentage width for something and have a pixel value for margin or padding, make sure you use a calc to subtract the cumulative pixel value from the width, or else it'll cause issues with scaling.

Comment: This is overcompensating for what box-sizing: border-box does naturally (and some more specific html).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

p {
  padding: 1em;
  }

section {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#999999;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
aside {
    background-color: #F9E903;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px   
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<section>
  <p>A technology services company supporting the solid rocket motor industry, airbag igniters, as well as Statistical Process Control support and training for manufacturing industries in general.</p></section>

<aside class="sidebar"><p>Content for  class "sidebar" Goes Here</p></aside>

<footer>
  <div class="footer-wrapper"><p>Content for class "footer" Goes Here</p></div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi you need 1. box-sizing: border-box and 2. You don't need to display: block, the html5 elements are already block elements. I also am applying padding to paragraphs inside the section and aside, if you add padding directly to them it disturbs the widths of the layout and they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

add global box-sizing like below

`* {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box:
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box:
   box-sizing: border-box;
}`

The above will factor in your padding, margin and border added to any of your block and inline-block element (like `padding: 20px` that you added to section).

then remove `display: block;` from aside and section (they are already block element)